# DOJO ... dojo/_base/xhr vs dojo/request API

Tags: dojo, xmlhttprequest, request

I have a requirement to us DOJO. While unit testing, I am using a simple *.json file and I am making a simple xhr.get or request.get call as shown in the code.

However, dojo/request fails to parse the json that it receives when I use the config option "handleAs:'json'"

Here is the content of "roles.data.json" file:

```
{roles:["Role - A", "Role - B", "Role - C", "Role - D", "Role - E"]}
```

Here is the dojo code that does not work

```
    require([
        'dojo/dom',
        'dojo/on',
        'dojo/ready',
        'dojo/parser',
        'dojo/request',
        'dijit/registry',
        'dijit/form/Form',
        'dijit/form/TextBox',
        'dijit/form/ValidationTextBox',
        'dijit/form/ComboBox',
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function (dom, on, ready, parser, request, registry) {
        ready(function () {
            console.log("ready");
            request.get("http://localhost/dojofun/data/roles.data.json",     {
                //offending piece of code here, if I remove this, request works as string                   
                handleAs :'json',
                //headers : { 'mime-type': 'application/json' } 
            }).then (function (data) {
                try {
                    console.log(data)
                    //var d = eval(data);
                    console.log(data.roles[0]); 
                }
                catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }

            });

        });
    });
```

here is the dojo code that does work.

```
    require([
        'dojo/dom',
        'dojo/on',
        'dojo/ready',
        'dojo/parser',
        'dojo/_base/xhr',
        'dijit/registry',
        'dijit/form/Form',
        'dijit/form/TextBox',
        'dijit/form/ValidationTextBox',
        'dijit/form/ComboBox',
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function (dom, on, ready, parser, xhr, registry) {
        ready(function () {
            console.log("ready");
            xhr.get({
                url:"http://localhost/dojofun/data/roles.data.json",
                handleAs :'json',
                load:function (data) {
                        try {
                            console.log(data)
                            console.log(data.roles[0]); 
                        }
                        catch (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    }    
            });

        });
    });
```

My question is, when I am using request.get, what am I missing? Are there extra imports that I have to make?

===============

Ok! found the error.. This is stupid but your JSON has to be in double quotes .... single quotes cause Syntax error. the correct JSON now looks like this:

```
{"roles":["Role - A", "Role - B", "Role - C", "Role - D", "Role - E"]}
```

Comment: Are there any errors indicated in the JavaScript console? Can you add an error callback to your `.then()` and log any error object?

Comment: No, no errors ....it doesn't seem to go into --> then(function (data){})

Comment: Without an error callback, you are ignoring any errors during the xhr call: `then(function(data){}, function(error) {console.log(error)})`

Comment: I did get the following error:                                      XHR finished loading: "http://localhost/dojofun/data/roles.data.json".
SyntaxError
arguments: Array[1]
0: "'"
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
get message: function () { [native code] }
get stack: function () { [native code] }
response: Object
set message: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
type: "unexpected_token"
__proto__: Error
arguments: undefined
constructor: function SyntaxError() { [native code] }
name: "SyntaxError"
stack: undefined
type: undefined
__proto__: d
 modifyuser.html:134

Comment: But don't understand where the token is not expected???

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had two guesses:

1. Your JSON is malformed. Technically, all JSON field names and strings must be: "double quoted."
2. You are [not sending the proper `Content-Type: application/json` header](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/ajax/):

> In addition to the encoding the data as JSON in the response, set the
>   Content-Type header to application/json, either using server
>   configuration such as Apache's AddType or adding it to the header with
>   the server side code.

---

I guess it was #1